ROS2-humble 'std::runtime_error' what(): can't subtract times with different time sources, on the startup of another ros2 node
I have 2 nodes, one called reset_node and another called sbus_node. Reset_node compiles and runs just fine but as soon as I launch sbus_node, which reset_node is subscribed to I get

"std::runtime_error'   what():  can't subtract times with different time sources".

Usually, I have seen that this error is due to trying to subtract time from different sources, but I am confused because I am only using this->now(). What could be the problem? My code is below..
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "sbus_serial/msg/sbus.hpp"
#include "std_msgs/msg/string.hpp"
#include <chrono>
#include <array>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

class ResetNode : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
    ResetNode() : Node("reset_node")
    {
        // Subscribe to sbus topic
        subscription_ = this->create_subscription<sbus_serial::msg::Sbus>(
            "/sbus", 10, std::bind(&ResetNode::reset_callback, this, std::placeholders::_1));
        // Initialize variables
        channel_indexes_ = {0, 1, 2, 3};
        channel_threshold_ = -10;
        reset_requirement_ = false;
        cooldown_duration_ = 10.0;  // Cooldown duration (in seconds) to not repeatedly trigger the reset
        cooldown_expired_ = true;
    }

private:
    // Callback function when joystick message is received
    void reset_callback(const sbus_serial::msg::Sbus::SharedPtr msg)
    {
        current_time_ = this->now();
        
        // Check if the combination is recieved
        if (std::abs(msg->mapped_channels[channel_indexes_[1]]) < 10 && 
            std::abs(msg->mapped_channels[channel_indexes_[3]]) < 10 &&
            msg->mapped_channels[channel_indexes_[0]] == -100 &&
            msg->mapped_channels[channel_indexes_[2]] == 100 &&
            cooldown_expired_)
        {
            if (!reset_requirement_)
            {
                // Combination initiated, record the time
                reset_requirement_ = true;
                action_started_time_ = current_time_;
            }
            else
            {
                // Combination is still being initiated, calculate the duration
                auto action_duration = current_time_ - action_started_time_;
                RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Action initiated...");

                if (action_duration.seconds() > 5.0)
                {
                    // Combination has been initiated for more than 5 seconds, perform the action
                    perform_action();
                    // Reset the flag 
                    reset_requirement_ = false;
                    // Raise cooldown flag
                    cooldown_expired_ = false;
                    // Start cooldown timer
                    cooldown_started_time_ = current_time_;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Combination dismissed, reset the flag
            reset_requirement_ = false;
            auto current_cooldown_duration = current_time_ - cooldown_started_time_;

            RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Action not initiated or on cooldown...");

            if (cooldown_duration_ < current_cooldown_duration.seconds())
            {
                cooldown_expired_ = true;
            }
        }
    }

    void perform_action()
    {
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Action initiated for 5 seconds, performing action...");
        // Some code...
    }

    rclcpp::Subscription<sbus_serial::msg::Sbus>::SharedPtr subscription_;
    std::array<int, 4> channel_indexes_;               
    int channel_threshold_; 
    bool reset_requirement_;            
    rclcpp::Time action_started_time_;
    rclcpp::Time cooldown_started_time_;
    rclcpp::Time current_time_;
    bool cooldown_expired_;
    double cooldown_duration_;   
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);

    auto node = std::make_shared<ResetNode>();
    rclcpp::spin(node);

    rclcpp::shutdown();
    return 0;
}
```


Is it possible that the 'outer else clause' in the callback gets executed before its 'inner else clause' has been executed?
If so, following line is executed
 auto current_cooldown_duration = current_time_ - cooldown_started_time_;

before cooldown_started_time_ is initialized.

yup, that fixes it, overlooked it.  thanks
